# How to access dimensions of widget at runtime?

Tags: python, flet

How do I can have access to a widget dimensions (width, height) in flet (python) at runtime or from other widget in the page?
I tried to access to the

```
widget.width
```

property directly but I believe it doesn't have read permissions.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the widget's width/height.
Default you can get only the NoneType value.

Example,
resize the window's height to change widgets attribute.
The widget's value will be moved:

```
import flet
from flet import Text, Page

def main(page: Page):
    label = Text('Resize window\'s height and value of this widget\'s height will be changed!')
    label.height = label.height = page.window_height * 0.4
    text = Text(label.height)
    page.add(label)
    page.add(text)
    
    def page_resize(e):
        label.height = page.window_height * 0.4
        text.value = label.height
        label.update()
        text.update()

    page.on_resize = page_resize
            
if __name__ == '__main__':
    flet.app(target=main)
```

Comment: That is not the problem described. You are setting the label height and make it visible before accessing it. I just want to access the value that it has at runtime, not set it. Try accessing the "label.height" without setting it to "page.window_height * 0.4". It returns "None".

Comment: "Default you can get only the NoneType value."
The page.window_height only for the demonstration for the change of widget's height.

Comment: remove the two lines in which you set label.height and try again. The label still has a height, but the property is not accessible.